# Modular $TERM for different terminal emulators

Tags: terminal, xterm, terminal-emulator, terminal-multiplexer

Is there a way to set different `$TERM` for different terminal emulators.  For example if I am in xterm the `$TERM` will read `xterm-256color`, in urxvt `urxvt-256color`, in sakura `xterm-256color` and in `tmux` `screen-256color`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general method. As [observed by vinc17](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159413), different terminal emulators let you configure the `TERM` value in different ways, if at all.

You can drop terminfo configuration files into your home directory, organized as `~/.terminfo/INITIAL-LETTER/VALUE`. For example, if you wish for `xterm` to point to the 256-color entry, on a typical machine,  you could do

```
mkdir -p ~/.terminfo/x
ln -s /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ~/.terminfo/x/xterm
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in your terminal configuration. For instance, with Xterm, this can be done via the X resources. You can do this via the Xterm app-defaults:

```
*termName: xterm-256color
```

or via a `-tn xterm-256color` option. This is similar for rxvt.

Comment: is there a universal file for this job. someone told my about alias. but I could figure that out?

Comment: @r004 There is no universal file. Worse than that, each terminal has its own method to configure `$TERM`, and I've already seen terminals where the possible `$TERM` values were hardcoded.